# Convert grayscale image to cross-hatch shading

Tags: image, imagemagick, grayscale

I have a grayscale image that I would like to convert into cross-hatched shading so it can be printed by a black and white only printer.

Is this possible with any postprocessing tools, such as ImageMagick's convert?

TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes imagemagick is the tool you want.  First you may look at the [monochrome](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#monochrome) section to see the basics, and depending on the effect you want, you can also try [ordered dithering](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#ordered-dither) to get that “newspaper” effect, or [custom thresholds](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#thresholds_xml) to get a shading effect however you like; a basic example is written in the section to give you an effect like:

> [image: before][image: and][image: after]

Comment: Ah! It's called dither! That's why I could not find anything: I was searching for cross-hatching! Thanks - that works perfectly.